# How to bind the value from angular 2 to polymer components

Tags: angular, polymer-1.0

Could you please help me out, how to bind the values from angular 2 components to Polymer components.

my-input.html -->Polymer Components

login.component.html -->Angular 2 
 (here i am using polymer components).

Whatever user is entered here(angular 2) -->bind the values to Polymer 
(my-input.html)

Thanks,

Comment: Please post your code. What have you tried?

Comment: In Polymer side, i created the below component using paper-input, like In input-box.html       <paper-input label="{{label}}" maxlength="12" </paper-input> ,     In angular component i imported input-box.html and i used polymer paper-input text box. After tat it is displaying polymer components in angular 2.Finally i have to  pass tat value to polymer.